# Question concerning divisibility

Tags: number-theory

> This may seem like a really stupid question, but how would one
>   rigorously prove that for any $n > 2$, $n - 1$ does not divide $n$?

I thought of a proof by induction since obviously $2$ does not divide $3$. Then we assume $n - 1$ does not divide $n$. But somehow I am sutcked there. Maybe we can use integer division to say that $n = (n - 1)p + q$ for some nonzero integer $q$ and then add $1$ to get $n + 1 = np - p + q + 1$.

Comment: If $n-1$ dvides $n$, then $n-1$ divides $n-(n-1)=1$. Do you consider that to be rigorous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By euclidean algorithm,

$$gcd(n,n-1)=1$$

Hence for $n>2$, $n-1$ does not divide $n$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that, for $n>2$,

$$n\equiv 0 \mod{n-1}$$

$\implies$

$$n-1\equiv -1 \mod{n-1}$$

$\implies$

$$n-1\equiv n-2 \mod{n-1}$$

$\implies$

$$1\equiv 0 \mod{n-1}$$

which is impossible since $n>2$.